# after setting image as src or background, how can I make it invisible during the animation

Tags: android, animation, imageview, visible

I have an imageView and its default image like

```
  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/imagesifir"

            />
```

But I have an animation which starts when a user clicks a button. During animation imagesifir is visible but I don't want it to be. When I click button, imagesifir should not be visible.

How can I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: When you click the button, grab the view by id and run imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Does that work?

Comment: it affects all ImageViev and I want to be invisible so I try it as invisible. All hole is invisible so nothing shown

Answer (score 0):

If you want to making invisible but not hole on imageviews place.Add this code to your onclick method.It will completely remove imageview from layout.

```
ImageView image=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Let me know if your issue solved.